# Oracles SQLDEV:GAUGE - how do I manipulate the values and colors?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

**BACKGROUND:**
I am working with adding a visual-aspect to historic change on a certain value (eg. rain-data). I want to make a gauge that shows the new rain-data entry in relation to the avg historic rain-data. So with every data entry I want the meter-bar (the black one) to show how much the rain differs from the avg value. What I struggle with is that the color-schema is a bit missrepresentive. I don't want the person that looks at the gauge to think that it's bad when the meter is low (since then it will lay in the red area of the gauge).

**QUESTION:**
Is there any way to invert the color-schema so that the gauge is green-orange-red? Or (for fun) making it green-orange-green?

If you look at my code-example under I've summerized all the different values and thresholds I've identified for the gauge. I've made the exampel simple so I didn't include the code for setting the meter-bar for rain-data in comparison to the avg rain-data. So what's missing from the exampel down under is the code that mainly circles around setting the avg-thresholds and meter-bar value for the last "0" in the "sqldev:gauge-code").

**CODE:**

```
--test with different values
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:0:100:0' graph_________ from dual union all --orange
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:100:100:0' graph_________ from dual union all --red
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:0:0:0' graph_________ from dual union all --green
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:0:0:65' graph_________ from dual union all --adding meter-gauge threshold for green background
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:0:0:66' graph_________ from dual union all --adding meter-gauge threshold for switching to yellow background
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:0:0:91' graph_________ from dual union all --adding meter-gauge threshold for switching to red background
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:35:70:0' graph_________ from dual union all -- green bar, red to 35% and orange to 70% of the bar
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:35:70:65' graph_________ from dual union all -- green bar, red to 35% and orange to 70% of the bar & meter-gauge to 65%
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:35:70:66' graph_________ from dual union all --threshold for when meter-gauge turns right block yellow
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:35:70:90' graph_________ from dual union all
select 'SQLDEV:GAUGE:0:100:35:70:91' graph_________ from dual --threshold for when meter-gauge turns right block red
; 

--I understand the different 0:s as such.
--1st 0 as min,
--2nd 0 as max,
--3d as lower threshold,
--4th as upper threshold,
--5th as value for the meter-bar
--the 5th value also changes the bars right-most color
--when the meter-bar reaches certain thresholds
```

I have tried different conversions on my data to make the gauge behave the way I want. With conversions I mean that I've tried to multiplying my rain-data and avg rain-data with different values, such as *100 or *1000.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15846_01/doc.21/e15222/intro.htm#RPTUG41364) and some OTN queries suggest this isn't configurable.

Comment: Hmm, you are probably right. I was starting to think the tool wasn't configured to work in the way I was hoping it would. Anyhow thanks for the input!

Comment: Consider a text replacement... https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/09/space-report-from-sql-developer-in-sqlcl/ no colors involved